# Movie PHP script

Tags: php

so I have the code done so far but I am getting an error about can't redefine movies and I have a feeling it's something small and stupid but I just can't seem to figure this out. I need to reate a Movies class that determines the cost of a ticket to a cinema, based on the moviegoer's age. Assume that the cost of a full-price ticket is $10. Assign the age to a private data member. Use a public member function to determine the ticket price.

First code which is Movies.html

```
<!--Movies.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Movies</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the movies!</h1>

<p>Enter your age to determine your price.</p>

<form action="Admissions.php" method="POST"> 
<p>Age <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Second file Admissions.php

```
<?php
include('Movies.php');

$age = $_POST['age'];
$price = 10;
$movies = new Movies($age);
$ticketPrice = $movies->getPrice($price);

echo"<p>The ticket price is $ticketPrice </p>\n";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Third file Movies.php

```
    <!--Movies.php-->

<?php

    class Movies {

    private $age = 0;
    private $ticketPrice = 10.00;

    function __construct($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    function getPrice($ticketPrice) {
        // use switch to manage age
        switch ($this->age) {
            case ($this->age < 5):
                $this->ticketPrice = 0;
                break;
            case ($this->age > 5 && $this->age < 18):
                $this->ticketPrice = $ticketPrice / 2;
            case ($this->age >= 18 && $this->age <= 55):
                $this->ticketPrice = $ticketPrice;
                break;
            case ($this->age > 55):
                $this->ticketPrice = $ticketPrice - (float) ("2.00");
                break;
        }

        return $this->ticketPrice;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php, if you have a method named the same as the class it's treated as the constructor. So you're essentially saying `Movie::Movie()` when you run your:

```
$ticketPrice = new Movies();
```

Your error is being thrown because each method name has to be unique. You can't have 2 methods/functions called `Movies`.

---

Not to mention, your class & script is riddled with errors. If you're going to implement an OOP approach, best to read up on how exactly to achieve that. (*Good on you for trying though!*).

Your class would function more efficiently if it looked like this:

```
class Movies {

    private $age = 0;
    private $ticketPrice = 10.00;

    function __construct($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    function getPrice($ticketPrice) {
        // use switch to manage age
        switch ($this->age) {
            case ($this->age < 5):
                $this->ticketPrice = 0;
                break;
            case ($this->age > 5 && $this->age < 18):
                $this->ticketPrice = $ticketPrice / 2;
            case ($this->age >= 18 && $this->age <= 55):
                $this->ticketPrice = $ticketPrice;
                break;
            case ($this->age > 55):
                $this->ticketPrice = $ticketPrice - 2;
                break;
        }

        return $this->ticketPrice;
    }
}
```

Now this allows you to run it like this:

```
// instantiate class
$age = $_POST['age'];
$price = 10;
$movies = new Movies($age);
$ticketPrice = $movies->getPrice($price);

echo echo"<p>The ticket price is $ticketPrice </p>\n";
```

<sup>*The above is an example and you'll need to work it to suite your implementation.*</sup>

[**DEMO**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#Msa5MvJR4)

---

**Update**

To answer your comment about the class not being found. I want you to put that `Movies` class into a file called `Movies.php`. Just the php code, nothing else. **NO** html at all.

Now in your Admissions.php file, I want you to change that to this:

```
<!--Admissions.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Movies</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
include('Movies.php');
$age = $_POST['age'];
$price = 10;
$movies = new Movies($age);
$ticketPrice = $movies->getPrice($price);

echo"<p>The ticket price is $ticketPrice </p>\n";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Making sure, each file is in the same directory to ensure it gets included into the `Admissions.php` script.

Comment: Alright, I tried moving this around a bit more but I am getting an error stating the class "Movies" was not found on the line $movies = new Movies($age);

Comment: @Wolfenacht Update your question with the code as it is now. As you need to include the class so that you can actually call it.

Comment: Alright I updated the code, I am also looking in a php book online to see if there are more hints on this. I'm beyond new at this. Thanks. I did add a require_once("Movies.php") and that got rid of one error just to produce another. Haha

Comment: Admissions.php needs to include Movies.php and remove html at the top

Comment: Yeah I figured out the Include part right after you updated it. Now when I run this I am getting an unexpected $age variable. Gonna try looking up what is going on in that area now.

Comment: @Wolfenacht You need to handle the form submission properly and ensure `$_POST['age']` is getting set correctly.

Comment: I think I got it sir, I missed a ; at the include which threw the error. Then the get_price was undefined so I changed that to getPrice and so far it is working, Let me test it out a few more times and i'll update it if it works.